# Java - How to convert a large number into a number with less digits and "E" as done by calculators?

Tags: java, integer, biginteger

I want to use mathematical expression in my Android app, I am using int data types only. But sometimes the output of the expression gets too big to hold by a int. What kind of data type should I use to convert the large output into a number with "E" in it?

Comment: NumberFormat and scientific notation, of course.  That's just a rendering issue.  Doubles are represented as IEEE floating point numbers in memory; that never changes.

Comment: see whenever the output value exceeds the maximum value of int, it always shows 2,147,483,647 (max val. of int) as the output? Suppose the expression is 10 000 000 000 x 10 000 000 000 = “ the answer is too big, int cannot hold it, so it gives 2,147,483,647 as output which is wrong!! How do I get the actual output (1e+20) for such large expression ?

Comment: int being too big is a separate issue.  Java is strongly typed: if you try to put a value into an int you'll get an overflow.  It doesn't switch to double to save you from yourself.

Comment: thanks @duffymo for some extra info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, If you want to store very big numbers in memory (that are too big for an int) and possibly do some math with them you'd have to use something like [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
import java.math.*;

BigInteger number = new BigInteger("12345678954646565757"); // very large number
BigInteger anotherNumber = new BigInteger("5");
number = number.add(anotherNumber);
```

Then, If you want to format this value with a scientific notation, use [NumberFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/NumberFormatter.html):

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.######E0");
String str = formatter.format(number);
System.out.println(str); // prints "1.234568E19"
```

Comment: will it be able to handle large numerical values with decimals as well? If not, what is its float or double equivalent ?

Comment: @Saibbyweb You can try [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for this

Comment: Perfect! Now the last one please.(which exactly was the main part of the question). How do I use NumberFormatter to replace multiple digits with E ? What exactly is replaced by E while using NumberFormatter?

Comment: @Saibbyweb Edited my answer.